# databse not configured error while insert record in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, configuration

I configured second database in laravel with name Test. but when i used to insert data in second database's table. It shows me an error, database not configured please help me to find where is my mistake?
I already make configuration to add new database in project. i changed .env file and database.php file in config folder. but nothing can help me.

database.php

```
    'mysql2' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => '3306',
                'database' => 'Test',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'unix_socket' => '',
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
            ],
```

.env

```
    DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql2
    DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
    DB_DATABASE_SECOND=Test
    DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
    DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=
```

SellerSelectProduct.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class SellerSelectProduct extends Model
    {
        protected $connection = 'Test';
        protected $fillable = ['product_id'];
    
        public function product(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
        }
    }
```

SellerBaseController.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Category;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\SellerSelectProduct;
    
    class SellerBaseController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
    
        public function someMethod()
        {
            $someModel = new SellerSelectProduct;
            $someModel->setConnection('Test');
            $something = $someModel->find(1);
            return $something;
        }
    
    }
```

SellerProductController.php

```
    <?php
    
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\City;
    use App\State;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\SellerSelectProduct;
    
    class SellerProductController extends SellerBaseController
    {
        public function someMethod()
        {
            $someModel = new SellerSelectProduct;
            $someModel->setConnection('Test');
            $something = $someModel->find(1);
            return $something;
        }
        
        public function index(State $state)
        {
            return $state->Cities;
        }
    
        public function addproducts(Request $request){
            SellerSelectProduct::insert($request->data);
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Selected product list updated successfully'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you named the connection `mysql2` not `Test`

Comment: i renamed from mysql2 to test, but it did not work. now it shown base table or view not found error, while insert record.

Answer (score -1):

**a sample of  a second  conection.**

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql2
DB_HOST2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT2=3306
DB_DATABASE2=
DB_USERNAME2=
DB_PASSWORD2=
```

*database.php*

```
'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST2', ''),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET2', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

To have an effect on clean or cache changes with or optimize handmade php command.